# How does this async function snippet work in the execution context in JS?

Tags: javascript, async-await

I am learning Javascript and I came across of JS snippet. I don't understand how it works

```js
let hello = () => Promise.resolve("Hello")

async function fun() {
  console.log("Inside")
  const result = await hello()
  console.log(result)
}

console.log("Start")
fun()
console.log("End")
```

The result in the console

```
Start
Inside
End
Hello
```

I don't understand why End is printed before Hello despite the await keyword used. I would like to understand how this snippet would work in the event loop. More specifically what happens when fun() is pushed into the call stack

Answer (score 0):

In `JavaScript`, when an asynchronous function is called, it doesn't block the execution of subsequent code. The `await` keyword inside an `async` function causes the function to pause and wait, but it doesn't block the execution of other code outside the `async` function. This is why *"End"* is printed before *"Hello"*.